# How to configure Boost.Python using bjam syntax?

Tags: c++, boost-python, bjam

I am trying to using Boost.Python.

My system is:

Visual Studio 2012 + Windows7 64-bit + Python 2.7.5 32-bit + Boost 1.54.

Now, I think the Boost.Python is installed,  and I can find .dll and .lib files at `C:\local\boost_1_54_0\lib32-msvc-11.0`, such as `boost_python-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib`.

Then I'm trying to run an example at `C:\local\boost_1_54_0\libs\python\example\quickstart` in Command Prompt as follows:

> bjam toolset=msvc toolset=msvc --verbose-test --debug-configuration test

Then I have some warning as:

> notice: [python-cfg] ...requested configuration matched!
>
> notice: [python-cfg] Details of this Python configuration:
>
> notice: [python-cfg]   interpreter command: "C:\Python2.7.5\python"
>
> notice: [python-cfg]   include path: "C:\Python2.7.5\Include"
>
> notice: [python-cfg]   library path: "C:\Python2.7.5\libs"
>
> notice: [python-cfg]   DLL search path: "C:\Python2.7.5"

Besides, there are linking errors:

> LINK : warning LNK4001: no object files specified; libraries used LINK
>   : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
>   bin\test_embed.test\msvc-11.0\debug\test_embed.exe : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I think that there could be something wrong with the configuration file. In [Boost.Python Instruction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/building.html), I find that there are two files could matter, which are `user-config.jam`, and `boost-build.jam`.

For `user-config.jam`, I find it at `C:\local\boost_1_54_0\tools\build\v2`, and its content is:

> using msvc : 11.0 ;
>
> using python : 2.7 : C:\\Python2.7.5\\ ;

For `boost-config.jam`, it is everywhere! I don't know which one should I modify. I guess it should be the one that in the same directory with the example. But what its content should be?

Also, I am still not sure if this problem is caused by wrong configuration files or by poor installation of Boost.Python.

Is there a tutorial of bjam syntax? I've googled about it, but every time I was lead back to Boost tutorial.

Can anyone help me work around this? Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

have you checked `the user-config.jam` in your home directory:

`ECHO %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`

the next point is that your user-config.jam isn't complete for your python configuration..

here is an example:

```
# -------------------
# MSVC configuration.
# -------------------

# Configure msvc (default version, searched for in standard locations and PATH).
# using msvc ;

# Configure specific msvc version (searched for in standard locations and PATH).
using msvc : 10.0 : C:\\app\\tools\\MSVisualStudio2010\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe ;


# ---------------------
# Python configuration.
# ---------------------

# Configure specific Python version.
# using python : 3.1 : /usr/bin/python3 : /usr/include/python3.1 : /usr/lib ;

using python 
    : 2.5                   # Version
    : C:\\app\\tools\\Python25\\python.exe      # Python Path
    : C:\\app\\tools\\Python25\\include         # include path
    : C:\\app\\tools\\Python25\\libs            # lib path(s)
    : <define>BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1
    ;
```

Comment: How does one use spaces in jam files?


using python 
    : 3.6                   # Version
    : "D:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe"      # Python Path
    ;